# Calculation to get the right resistor

Tags: resistors

I have the following threshold value: UVLO Rising : 9.68V - 10.46V UVLO Falling : 8.94V - 9.16V

I am using LM25069, and I would like to find out how to get the right resistor for R1. Based on the datasheet of LM25069, R1 = (Vuvh - Vuvl) / 20uA

NOTE: There were some gotten to use 49k9 1% resistor. But I could not figure out how can one get to that value based on the formula calculation above.

Thanks.

Comment: ... (10V−9V)/20uA?

Comment: Ignacio's math works. (10-9)/0.00002=50k.

Answer (score 0):

One chooses the UV thresholds and hysteresis and then choose R1,R2,R3 or R1,R2,R3,R4 method depending on precision required. In this case, hypothetical hysteresis required was 1V. Thus 50k for nom. 20uA hysteresis current.